# SWT Sectioned Table & Scrolling

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm trying to display an SWT table inside a form section, but am having problems with column resizing and scrolling.

I've attached some sample code that can be placed in a ViewPart of an Eclipse pluging (3.7 is the version I'm using). If you run the code, and resize the column to the right, the table gains a horizontal scrollbar (which is what I want).

Now if I collapse the section (click the arrow to the left of "Section Title"), the view gains a horizontal scrollbar (which i don't want). Expanding the section again, the view scroll remains, and now the table no longer has one.

I'm looking for a way (probably some awful combination of nested composites) to stop the table being wider than the view, and would appreciate any suggestions.

```
public class ExampleView extends ViewPart {
  /** Note: other fields / methods removed to condense snippet */

  private FormToolkit toolkit;
  private ScrolledForm scrolledForm;

  public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
            parent.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    toolkit = new FormToolkit(parent.getDisplay());
    scrolledForm = toolkit.createScrolledForm(parent);
    scrolledForm.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledForm.setText("Form Title");

    scrolledForm.getBody().setLayout(new FillLayout());
    // here's the modification for the solution
    scrolledForm.getBody().setLayout(
            new BoundedLayout(new FillLayout(), true));

    final Section section = toolkit.createSection(scrolledForm.getBody(),
            Section.DESCRIPTION | Section.TITLE_BAR | Section.TWISTIE
                    | Section.EXPANDED);

    section.addExpansionListener(new ExpansionAdapter() {
        public void expansionStateChanged(ExpansionEvent e) {
            scrolledForm.reflow(true);
        }
    });
    section.setText("Section Title");

    final Table table = toolkit.createTable(section, SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(table);

    table.setLinesVisible(true);
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setItemCount(10);

    TableColumn col = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    col.setText("Column A");
    col.setWidth(150);
    col.setResizable(true);
    col.setMoveable(true);

    TableColumn col2 = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    col2.setText("Column B");
    col2.setWidth(150);
    col2.setResizable(true);
    col2.setMoveable(true);

    section.setClient(table);
  }
}
```

Comment: Minor update - i see from the source that the call to `section.setLayout(new FillLayout());` is ignored by Section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's a solution i've come up with using a custom Layout. It wraps another layout, but can bound the `computeSize` to either the width or height of the parent composite - basically only allowing scrolling in one direction (if there is an easier way to force the `ScrolledForm` to do this please let me know!).

There are some nasty-ish reflection hacks that need to be applied as the `computeSize` and `layout` methods are `protected`

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Layout;

public class BoundedLayout extends Layout {
  protected Layout delegateLayout;

  protected Method computeSizeMethod;
  protected Method layoutMethod;

  protected boolean widthBound;

  public BoundedLayout(Layout delegateLayout, boolean widthBound) {
      setDelegateLayout(delegateLayout);
      this.widthBound = widthBound;
  }

  public Layout getDelegateLayout() {
      return delegateLayout;
  }

  public void setDelegateLayout(Layout delegateLayout) {
      this.delegateLayout = delegateLayout;

      try {
          computeSizeMethod = delegateLayout.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                "computeSize", Composite.class, int.class, int.class,
                boolean.class);
          computeSizeMethod.setAccessible(true);

          layoutMethod = delegateLayout.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                "layout", Composite.class, boolean.class);
          layoutMethod.setAccessible(true);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
  }

  @Override
  protected Point computeSize(Composite composite, int wHint, int hHint,
        boolean flushCache) {
    // get comp size to make sure we don't let any children exceed it
    Point compSize = composite.getSize();

    try {
        Point layoutComputedSize = (Point) computeSizeMethod.invoke(
                delegateLayout, composite, wHint, hHint, flushCache);

        if (widthBound) {
            layoutComputedSize.x = Math.min(compSize.x,
                    layoutComputedSize.x);
        } else {
            layoutComputedSize.y = Math.min(compSize.y,
                    layoutComputedSize.y);
        }

        return layoutComputedSize;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void layout(Composite composite, boolean flushCache) {
    try {
        layoutMethod.invoke(delegateLayout, composite, flushCache);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue, and i dont really investigated the details but somewow when i define some LayoutData on the Table and give them a widthHint with 0, everything works fine:

GridData tableLayoutData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
tableLayoutData.widthHint = 0;
table.setLayoutData(tableLayoutData);

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `Section.COMPACT` style to your Section then the width of the section will only be resized in expanded state. In collapsed state it will go back to normal size.

If you don't want the Section to increase in width after expanding again, I think you'll have to use a workaround in the `ExpansionAdapter`. Store the width manually when collapsing and set it back when expanding.

Btw, I'd recommend using [WindowBuilder](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/) to build GUIs so its easier to tweak and move stuff around.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. The `Section.COMPACT` style does exactly what you said, and i looked into `ExpansionAdapter` too, but it still seems to hinge on the Layout (which overrides any attempt of mine to manually set the size). I think i'm basically going to write my own layout, similar to `FillLayout` but will have some magic in the `computeSize` method to ignore the preferred size of the table